# How to get the value of the element size when element inspecting in browser?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to get the value of the element size when element inspecting in browser ? I mean, how to get `402x48` via selenium or something ?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pIrs.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use selenium for this

`getAttribute(arg0)` method.

```
String width = driver.findElement(image locator).getAttribute("width");
String height = driver.findElement(image locator).getAttribute("height");
```

Comment: `.size`, or `.getSize()` for other languages, is preferred.

Comment: Selenium API in java only have `.getSize() ` I'm not sure about the other languages. I hop it worked out for you .

Comment: I meant: `.getSize()` is preferred over the two `.getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath").size) # gives size of the element as width & height.
```